# Count +1 when specific element present in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have an array and we count a variable to +1 if number specific element found in an array. It gives an output 0.

Any help Why .?

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a',];

 let a = 0;

if (arr === 'a') {
 return a = a + 1;
} else {
return 'Invalid'; 
}

//Output is 0
```

Comment: It will return `invalid` because `arr` is an array, and is not `===` to `'a'`. The output is *not* `0`.

Comment: but a element can be found in arr right .?

Comment: you need to take an index for accessing the array value.

Comment: research `Array.reduce()`

Comment: @rayvic `===` doesn't check if an array contains a value, it checks if the two objects are equal. `'a'` is not equal to the entire array, so it's false.

Comment: @radarbob reduce() gives the total output value and add all the elements present in an arrray .

Comment: oops yes.. @Carcigenicate.

Comment: @rayvic, I'm thinking something like this `arr.reduce( (acc, ele) => if( ele === "x") acc++ )`

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the items of the array and check the value of it.

By taking the [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), you exit the function, which is actually not given. More than that, you want to count the other `'a'` as well.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', ],
    a = 0,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 'a') {
        a = a + 1;
    }
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: It is not clear, but i don't think he want to count the number of `a` elements, for the code he made I think he want to just check if exists

Comment: i think op wants to count all `'a'` items.

Comment: Maybe, but why the return of `Invalid`?

Comment: who knows ... it?